# Perturbative coupling for QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, non-perturbative

I'm confused about the definition of a perturbative coupling for QFT that it should be less than 4 $\pi$, because the higher order corrections comes of order $\lambda/(4 \pi)$ ..

Now why QCD is not perturvative at low energy because the coupling constant  approaches just 1 at this regine ?