# Definition of Perturbative

Tags: feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

When calculating a particle physics processes such as

$ a + b \rightarrow mediator \rightarrow c + d $

to do a Feynman diagram calculation we require the coupling between particle $a$, $b$ and the $mediator$ be small. This small is order 1. However is the upper limit of perturbativity 1, $\pi$, $2\pi$ or $4\pi$?

Comment: Related: [Perturbative coupling for QFT](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/288251).